# HttpPost SetEntity not working in httpclient v4 if KEY is same

Tags: java

I am using httpclient-4.3.5. 
Created method to set parameter

```
List<NameValuePair>) param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
public void setParameter(String key, String value) {
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, value));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param);
}
```

I am calling this method with key and value e.g. (key1, value1).First call its value is set to the respective key, again called this method with same key but different value e.g. (key1, value2) then value is not setting to respective key. when I am retrieving value I am getting first value (value1)

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: could you please post the code by which you are retrieving value/

Answer (score 0):

You are using `param = new ArrayList<>()`, so the substitution will not work. If you want to use a list, you have to iterate it until you find the index of the parameter you want to change, then use `param.set(index, replacement)`. Otherwise use a `Map<String, String>` to prepare the parameters, then convert to `List` when you invoke `httpPost.setEntity`

Answer (score 0):

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
```

Call this line outside of setParameter() because after setting value1 it immediately call httpPost.setEntity().

If I made mistake to pretemd question then please pose your whole code here....